# Clark Kent as Cold War Reporter

Tags: dc, superman

Did Clark Kent, as a reporter, ever react to the major impacts that journalism had during the Cold War, such as Watergate and the Iran-Contra Affair, or even modern stories like WikiLeaks?  Obviously Superman stories tend to be about Superman, but considering that his alter-ego is famously a reporter (and considering his ties to Lois Lane, who almost certainly would have had an opinion about those events) it seems natural for him to react to such journalism coups. It also seems like an interesting thing for him to explore as a character, being torn between his loyalty to "truth and justice" vs his trusting, optimistic nature.

Do any comics from the time depict Clark Kent's reactions to his peers in the news industry, or does Clark Kent mostly only serve as a beard for Superman?

Comment: More importantly, did Watergate, the Iran-Contra Affair, etc happen in the DC Universe?

Comment: True, although even if the details are different there is likely an equivalent event.  Marvel's WWII featured Hydra and Captain America, for example, but the war still happened.  I think it's unlikely that the whole of the Cold War, and the fear and social unrest that came with it, just straight-up didn't happen in the DC Universe.  Even if the scandals are attributed to Vandal Savage instead of the Ayatollah, or to Lex Luthor instead of Nixon, the same exploration of "Clark Kent as Reporter" could play out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Superman, as a reporter, would certainly have some emotional impact from these events. But many of them are controversial, and in the world of comics this could be interpreted wrongly.

It would be possible for the superman to take advantage in some events. But imagine if for example he was covering an event of war (Iraq for example) and he ended up supporting the US. It would be very bad for his image, but on the other hand he would support Israel was hated by the Americans.

It's healthier for him to create hypothetical situations and only attack the "evil", because in the real world we do not always know who is the "evil". He had an opinion as a reporter and Superman as another.

It would be very complicated to put it in a current controversy real situation and not "detonate" your image.

Comment: Very true, and a good point.  Do you know, though, did Clark Kent the Reporter do much, even with fictional events?  Exposing Vandal Savage's run for office, perhaps, or uncovering corruption at LexCorp?  Or is Kent's reporting career not really touched upon, real or fictional?

Comment: Seeing as that Superman has traditionally stood for "Truth, justice, and the American way", I don't think anyone would be too surprised if his actions or opinions supported the US.

Comment: That's kind of what I'm aiming for: Clark Kent's reactions when "truth and justice" are at odds with "the American way," such as political corruption.